# Phone validator needed

Tags: .net, validation

I need a phone validator in asp.net, here is the accepted phone number format:
123-4567
123-456-7890
1-123-456-7890
1-123-456-7890 x 1234
1-222-3456-7890

Thanks lots. I did find some existing discussion, either not working or not meeting my requirement. The "-" could be space or "."

Comment: I'd sugest starting here: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?categoryId=7&cattabindex=6&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 and modifying as necessary.  Regular Epxressions are one of those things you'll need to learn anyway if you're going to be properly validating data.  If you want a nice, cheap, good book on Regular Expressions I'd recommend http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004156.do but the book is just one idea. There are free resources all over the web for learning them including at MSDN.

Comment: Can I ask why you accepted the other answer?

Answer (score 3):

The C# port of Google's phone number validator ([libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)) is about the best phone number validator out there

https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

It can handle these requirements and many more.

For client-side validation you can use the JavaScript version available with [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).

Comment: Thanks, that's too complex, I am expecting a reg expression to do this

Comment: The tag it as regex not validator.

Comment: What if someone types in the number as `123.456.7890` or `(123)456-7890` or `123 456 7890` (or any of a number of other ways real users enter numbers)?  You will annoy your end users, and end up with a change request.  Solid handling of user input is important.

Comment: Totally agree with you, that's why I am seeking experienced people to write this for me instead of learning it myself from abc

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily using regex:

A possible example:

```
/^(([1-9]\-)?([1-9][0-9]{2}\-)?([1-9][0-9]{2}\-)([0-9]{4})( x [0-9]{4})?)$/
```

Although the requirements aren't too clear, so that may or may not work for what you need.

Edit since you edited your original question:

```
/^(([1-9](\-| |\.))?([1-9][0-9]{2}(\-| |\.))?([1-9][0-9]{2}(\-| |\.))([0-9]{4})( ?x ?[0-9]{4})?)$/
```

Comment: Using a regexp and refining it for your needs is the way to go.

Comment: I'll add that you might want to consider coming up with a regex on your own if you decide to go this route. It's a valuable skill to have.

Comment: There are tons of resources out there about regex. Just google "regex".

Comment: I tested both regex, 234-567-8901 didn't get passed; 1-234-567-8901 didn't get passed either. How come? Here is my code: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                        EnableTheming="True" ErrorMessage="Phone number format is incorrect, please corrent"
                        ValidationExpression="/^(([1-9]\-)?([1-9][0-9]{2}\-)?([1-9][0-9]{2}\-)([0-9]{4})( x [0-9]{4})?)$/"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: I don't know how the ASP validator works. You may have to remove the '/' at the beginning and the end. The regex is definitely correct.